# gstreamer muxing with x264enc

Tags: gstreamer, x264

I am trying to convert a DVD to mkv file with gstreamer. The pipeline I use is:

```
gst-launch -evv multifilesrc location="VTS_01_%d.VOB" index=1 ! dvddemux name=demuxer \
 matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test.mkv \
 demuxer.current_video ! queue ! mpeg2dec ! x264enc ! mux. \
 demuxer.current_audio ! queue ! ffdec_ac3 ! lamemp3enc ! mux.
```

Unfortunately the pipeline does not go beyond prerolling. When I replace x264enc with for instance ffenc_mpeg4, then everything works fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may work :

```
gst-launch filesrc location=file.vob \
  ! queue \
  ! dvddemux name=demuxer matroskamux name=mux \
  ! queue \
  ! filesink location=test.mkv demuxer.current_video\
  ! queue \
  ! ffdec_mpeg2video \
  ! ffdeinterlace  \
  ! x264enc \
  ! 'video/x-h264, width=720, height=576, framerate=25/1' \
  ! mux.  demuxer.current_audio \
  ! queue max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=10000000000 \
  ! ffdec_ac3 \
  ! audioconvert \
  ! lamemp3enc \
  ! mux.
```

Byte stream should be 0  - sorry for that earlier

You need to give the caps of the video after the x264enc 
and you need to increase the limits on the audio queue to handle the delay in x264enc

These two changes have the pipeline running at my end.

The deinterlacer is optional but desirable for interlaced content.

Comment: av501, this seems to work. Thanks a lot, man ! Now, my question is, how did you figure this out ? How do you debug these kinds of things ? How can you analyze why the pipeline does not start...? BTW: I see you also added audioconvert. Is that necessary ?

Comment: Adding "GST_DEBUG=<one of 2,3,4,5,6>"  before your pipeline command just before gst-launch will print debug statements and tell you lot of things. Then you need to scan for errors, warnings, sentences like "could not... " or "not compatible" etc  Audioconvert may not be necessary if the output of ac3 decoder is compatible with lame encoder but may be needed for files where the format is not compatible.